# tengo un problema con flask y webhook para un telegram-bot

Tags: python, flask, heroku, telegram, telegram-bot

estoy intentando crear una aplicacion en la cual pueda funcionar un bot de telegram y una appweb tipo frontend en el cual pueda por ejemplo editar a futuro el contenido de los comandos del telegram-bot.
El problema comienza cuando quiero realizar el deploy a heroku, puedo iniciar la aplicacion web pero no funciona el bot y si cambio el webhook, funciona el bot pero no la aplicacion web. Este es mi codigo

app.py

```
import os
import sys

import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, updater
from telegram.ext.commandhandler import CommandHandler
from resources.commands import *
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

token = "Telegram bot token"
heroku_app_name = "Heroku app name"

bot = telegram.Bot(token= token)
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/' + token, methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    updater = telegram.update.Update.de_json(request.get_json(force=True), bot)
    return 'OK'

def setWebhook():
    bot.setWebhook(webhook_url="https://{}.herokuapp.com/{}".format(heroku_app_name, token))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setWebhook()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))

dp = updater.dispatcher

dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("hello", hellothere))    

def hellothere(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("Hello There!!")
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bot</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello world!!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Procfile

```
web: python app.py
```

Comment: This is a spanish site, please translate your question.

Comment: perdon, soy nuevo en la plataforma